# Mysqldump with python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to save a mysql database dump in a python script. Here is what I have:

```
filepath = os.path.join(BACKUPS_FOLDER, '%s.sql' % date)
print filepath # /Users/david/Desktop/updates/_backups/2013-04-07.sql
subprocess.call(shlex.split('mysqldump -u root updates > %s' % filepath ))
```

I get the following error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"
```

What I am doing incorrectly here?

Comment: What happens when you enclose %s in quotes?  `"%s"`

Comment: I think you don't have the shell when calling mysqldump so it will pass `>` as a parameter (in this case as a table name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call mysqldump with the option `--result-file=file` (`subprocess.call(shlex.split('mysqldump -u root updates --result-file=%s' % filepath ))`)since it will interpret the `>` as a table name.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Would be good to note that Python 3.5 and higher, `subprocess.run` is the preferred API - https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, using `communicate()` to get the output and then write to a file:

```
date = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
filepath = os.path.join(BACKUPS_FOLDER, '%s.sql' % date)

args = shlex.split("mysqldump -u root updates")
p1 = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
dump_output = p1.communicate()[0]

f = open(filepath, "wb")
f.write(dump_output)
f.close()
```